# Swift Parse database relation

Tags: swift, database, parse-platform

For my app I'm using Parse Database and it works really good. But at this moment I really need to start using relations. I understand relations and all but I think I'm not using it the right way...

```
    (cellDataParse.object(forKey: "user") as! PFRelation).query().getFirstObjectInBackground { (obj, error) in
        let fullname = obj?.object(forKey: "name") as! String
        let username = obj?.object(forKey: "username") as! String
        cell.name.text = fullname + " (" + username + ")"
    }
```

So I have 2 classes in my database. Check-ins and Users, in check-ins there is a column with a relation to a user.
I have a tableview that loads the check-ins from a specific day. But it must display the name of a user.
At the moment it works perfectly but my question is, am I loading/getting the relation information in the correct way? I think I'm now making a connection with my database for each cell (with getfirstobjectinbackground). This looks really stupid ... or isn't this making a connection for each cell? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't do implicit unwrapping of your variables. This may cause a crash if the data field is nil or if it's not parseable.

Comment: @ZonilyJame okay thank you, but am I right that it makes a internet connection / request for each tablecell with getFirstObjectInBackground? Or is it just 1 time?

Comment: Hi, is this code inside `cellForRowAt Indexpath`?, If it is I suggest you query these items beforehand before loading them in the cell, and yes this will call and call and call and call everytime the `cell loads`